# Wait for a timer to complete before seeing the result

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval

I want to get the timer first, then see the result. When I open the page, and start the function `war()` it shows the result, then it shows the cooldown in the set color. I want to get the cooldown first, then the result.

JavaScript:

```
var points = 100;

function war() {

  var dealer = document.getElementById("dealer");
  var player = document.getElementById("player");
  var winner = document.getElementById("winner");
  var winner1 = document.getElementById("winner");
  var screen = document.getElementById("points");
  var dealercard = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
  var playercard = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
  dealer.innerHTML = dealercard;
  player.innerHTML = playercard;
  var skaiciuoklis = 5;
  var naujaselemnt = document.createElement("p");
  naujaselemnt.innerHTML = "Wait...     5 seconds.";
  var idwar;
  dealer.parentNode.replaceChild(naujaselemnt, dealer);

  idwar = setInterval(function() {
    skaiciuoklis--;
    if (skaiciuoklis < 0) {
      winner1.parentNode.replaceChild(dealer, naujaselemnt);
      clearInterval(idwar);
    } else {
      winner1.innerHTML = "Wait... " + skaiciuoklis.toString() + " seconds.";
    }
  }, 500);

  if (dealercard > playercard) {
    winner.style.color = "red";
    winner.innerHTML = "You lost 20 points";
  } else {
    winner.style.color = "green";
    winner.innerHTML = "You won 10 points!";
  }
  if (dealercard == playercard) {
    winner.style.color = "blue";
    winner.innerHTML = "WAR. You won 20 points!"
  }

  if (dealercard < playercard) {
    points = points + 10;
    screen.innerHTML = points;
  }

  if (dealercard == playercard) {
    points = points + 20;
    screen.innerHTML = points;
  }
  if (dealercard > playercard) {
    points = points - 20;
    screen.innerHTML = points;
  }
  if (points <= 0) {
    winner.style.color = "red";
    winner.innerHTML = "Game Over";
    alert("Game Over. REFRESH PAGE TO RETRY!");
    points = 100;
  }
```

Comment: It isn't clear what you're trying to accomplish or what your question is.

Comment: It would also help if you properly indent your code.

Comment: @Amy hopefully that helped

Comment: `dealer.parentNode.replaceChild(naujaselemnt, dealer);

  idwar = setInterval(function() {
    skaiciuoklis--;
    if (skaiciuoklis < 0) {
      winner1.parentNode.replaceChild(dealer, naujaselemnt);
      clearInterval(idwar);
    } else {
      winner1.innerHTML = "Wait... " + skaiciuoklis.toString() + " seconds.";
    }
  }, 500);`
 I would like to give priority to these lines

Comment: I can upload whole project, if it would help

Comment: When i start the website it shows  `var winner = document.getElementById("winner");`, then it start the countdown. I want to get that countdown first

Comment: Sorry if I got it wrong, but I guess you should reverse the order of these lines:
  `dealer.innerHTML = dealercard;`
  `player.innerHTML = playercard;`
  `naujaselemnt.innerHTML = "Wait...     5 seconds.";`

Comment: @Simonas - you want to strive to post a "[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)".

Answer (score 0):

You can use ES6 async await and move your timer to a separate function outside. You have a lot of variables and it isn't so clear but it looks like your timer is in the function war(). Javascript is asynchronous and it will move to next code even if you have a timer.

An example like this:

```
function timer(){
 // implement timer
}



 async function war() {

  // at the line u want to call the timer
  await timer();
 }
```